# Change OpenCL Compiler Rules

Tags: opencl

Is there a way to prevent the OpenCL compiler from throwing an error when it encounters illegal code like `x = 3 / 0;` or `x = sqrt(INFINITY / NAN);` in the kernel code?

I am ok if the answer stored in `x` is a meaningless number.  Just wondering, is it possible (perhaps by editing the compiler) to get all OpenCL functions and operations to ignore type - and output *something* if they are passed the right quantity of bytes?

Comment: you should probably name the compiler/SDK that you are using

Comment: I am using PyOpenCL on OSX - so I guess that means gcc is the compiler.

Comment: You can try passing "-w" for the options parameter of your clBuildProgram call (or PyOpenCL equivalent). The specification says that will inhibit all warning messages. However, the compiler might see these an errors rather than warnings.

Comment: @benshope Sry but you are wrong, the kernel compiler is not GCC, is the OpenCL platform compiler you are using (nVIDIA, AMD, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try some of these:
http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html

I would focus on:

**-cl-unsafe-math-optimizations:**

> Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that (a) assume that arguments and results are valid, (b) may violate IEEE 754 standard and (c) may violate the OpenCL numerical compliance requirements as defined in section 7.4 for single-precision floating-point, section 9.3.9 for double-precision floating-point, and edge case behavior in section 7.5. This option includes the -cl-no-signed-zeros and -cl-mad-enable options.

**-cl-finite-math-only:**

> Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic that assume that arguments and results are not NaNs or ±∞. This option may violate the OpenCL numerical compliance requirements defined in in section 7.4 for single-precision floating-point, section 9.3.9 for double-precision floating-point, and edge case behavior in section 7.5.